# Как правильно определить начало бинарного пакета, при чтении из последовательного порта

Tags: python, binary, последовательный-порт

Имеется протокол, в котором пакет начинается с фиксированого маркера размером 2 байта (`0x1010`).

У меня вопрос, как правильно и лаконично определить начало пакета при чтении? Читать сразу по два байта и сравнивать с маркером, или же читать по одному байту в поисках верной последовательности?
В данным момент у меня реализован второй вариант:

```
def _listen(self) -> None:
    try:
        while self._work:
            if self._connection.read(1)[0] == 0x10 and self._connection.read(1)[0] == 0x10:
                header = self._connection.read(3)
                payload = self._connection.read(header[1]-5)
                self._on_message_received(payload)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        return
```

Выглядит довольно громоздко, руки чешутся сразу читать по два байта сравнивать с маркером.
Но, насколько это будет отказоустойчиво? Ведь последовательный порт оперирует байтами, а не пакетам, что если чтение начнется сразу со второго байта маркера? В таком случае весь цикл чтения будет "сдвинут" на один байт. Такое возможно?

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что удастся упростить. Разве что в данном случае мне кажется понятнее была бы логика работы, если вместо `if ... and ...` сделать два вложенных `if`-а. Ну и я бы зарефакторил вызовы `self._connection.read(n)` в что-то типа `self.get_byte()` и `self.get_bytes(n)`, чтобы код был короче и понятнее. Или даже то что в `if` сделать как `self.is_byte(0x10)`. Главное, чтобы код был понятным, сейчас в основном лишние какие-то штуки типа `._connection` отвлекают от его понимания.

Comment: Сталкивался с подобной вашей задачей, правда там читал пакеты из файла, но сути не меняет. Тогда не придумал ничего лучше, чем сравнивать побайтно с маркером *(и сомневаюсь, что здесь можно придумать что-либо ещё, как выше указал @CrazyElf)*. А насчет `что если чтение начнется сразу со второго байта маркера?` не очень вас здесь понял, ведь если чтение начнется не с первого байта, то вы просто пропустите пакет не определив его. У вас просто не сработает условие.